# How to use Ruby's command line in-place-edit mode to remove lines from a text file

Tags: ruby, inplace-editing

I've been a long time perl user, and in perl you can easily remove lines from text files like this:

```
perl -pi -e 'undef $_ if m/some-condition/' file.txt
```

I'm trying to move my scripting to Ruby, which also does in-place-edit, so I wrote this:

```
ruby -pi -e '$_ = nil if $_ =~ /some-condition/' file.text
```

but that instead nullified the entire file. I then tried

```
ruby -pi -e 'nil if $_ =~ /some-condition/' file.text
```

but that didn't do anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: The second form works for me. Might it be your condition that is matching each line? `echo -e "a\nb\nc" > x ; ruby -pi -e '$_ = nil if $_ =~ /b/' x ; cat x` prints `a\nc` for me.

Comment: +1 for @Amadan, it works for me too

Comment: Yea, probably something wrong with my regex - now that I tested it again with the original expression and the original test data, it worked fine. @Amadan, if you put your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ruby -pi -e '$_ = nil if $_ =~ /some-condition/' file.text
```

should be correct. If it doesn't work, the problem is in `some-condition`. To demonstrate,

```
echo -e "a\nb\nc" > x ; ruby -pi -e '$_ = nil if $_ =~ /b/' x ; cat x
```

prints

```
a
c
```